# Cannot compare/validate passwords in view model in Nancy project?

Tags: c#, nancy

I have the following view model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    namespace Reflect.Web.Models.ViewModels
    {
        public class ManageUserAccountViewModel
        {
            public string Username { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public float UtcOffset { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Passwords don't match.")]
            public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }
            public int HourOfDay { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In one of my modules I call the following code:

```
var userModel = this.Bind<ManageUserAccountViewModel>();
var result = this.Validate(userModel);
```

Some how the validation result always returns IsValid == true, even when the valjues to be compared obviously are not. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: You ever get this working? I'm still having this exact problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `Compare` attribute is not yet supported in Nancy. If you look [here](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/tree/master/src/Nancy.Validation.DataAnnotations), you can see that there is not `CompareValidatorAdapter` defined.

You must implement your own for now (and if you do, just send it as a pull request, so the rest of the world can use it too).

Comment: Thanks! :-). Working on it as we speak. However, I just ran into a new issue with this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576299/where-do-i-find-objet-to-compare-in-comparevalidatoradapter-for-nancy