# Where do I find object to compare in CompareValidatorAdapter for Nancy?

Tags: c#, .net, nancy

I want to build a `CompareValidatorAdapter` for Nancy. Can any one give me some pointers as to where I can get the value to be compared?

```
public override IEnumerable<ModelValidationRule> GetRules(ValidationAttribute attribute, PropertyDescriptor descriptor)
{
    var ca = (CompareAttribute)attribute;

    yield return new ComparisonValidationRule(attribute.FormatErrorMessage,
        new[] { descriptor.Name },
        ComparisonOperator.Equal, <WHERE DO I GET THIS VALUE?>);
}
```

Should I use some sort of reflection technique? I have the feeling I am missing something obvious.

Comment: there is a CompareValidatorAdapter in nancy here: https://github.com/xt0rted/Nancy.Validation.DataAnnotations.Extensions/blob/master/src/Nancy.Validation.DataAnnotations.Extensions/CompareValidatorAdapter.cs

Comment: well it's not _in_ nancy but somewhere close to it :)

Comment: I finally got around to publishing that project to NuGet if it helps at all